# How to save DateTime to Cloud Firestore correct

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

In my app, I have created a chat. When someone is chatting with another user, their have to see when someone has sent his message. In my script, I tried to use the `DateTime`. But if someone sends messages for the last 10 minutes, for example, they all have the same time. The class `MessageTile` is for the message and the `addMessage` method is where I stored things when someone click on the send Icon like time. Does anyone know how I can get the right `Date` to save my time so that when someone sends his message at 12:00 and someone sends his message at 13:15 that this is showing in the chat??

[A Screenshot from my Chatscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYjj5.png)

```
class MessageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final bool sendByMe;
  final String time;

  MessageTile({@required this.message, @required this.sendByMe, @required this.time});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: sendByMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 3,
              bottom: 3,
              left: sendByMe ? 0 : 24,
              right: sendByMe ? 24 : 0),
          alignment: sendByMe ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            margin: sendByMe
                ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 30)
                : EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 17, bottom: 17, left: 20, right: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: sendByMe ? BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(9),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                ) :
                BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(9),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(9)),
                color: sendByMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.white
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(message,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                    fontSize: 12.5,),),
                Text( DateFormat("hh:mm").format(DateTime.parse(time.toString())) ,style:
                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Orbitron', fontSize: 7.0,) ,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Like so??

```
addMessage() {
    if (messageEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatMessageMap = {
        "sendBy": Constants.myName,
        "message": messageEditingController.text,
        'time': DateFormat("hh:mm").format(DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toLocal().toString())) ,
      };

      DatabaseService().addMessage(widget.chatRoomId, chatMessageMap);

      setState(() {
        messageEditingController.text = "";
      });
    }
  }
```

to that

```
 addMessage() {
    if (messageEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatMessageMap = {
        "sendBy": Constants.myName,
        "message": messageEditingController.text,
        'time': DateFormat("hh:mm").format(DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toLocal().toString())) ,
      };

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myChatCollection').doc().set({
        'timeStamp': ServerValue.timestamp
      });

      DatabaseService().addMessage(widget.chatRoomId, chatMessageMap);

      setState(() {
        messageEditingController.text = "";
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: you could look at the firestore docs for getting the data for your message

Comment: The thing is how can I display this from firestore. snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['time']?? No or?

Comment: When I put only the variable time in the Text like Text(time) then I got the error : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to store `Date and Time` in `Firestore` is to use the server's date and time. Using `DateTime.now()` to store time is discouraged because users can change their phone's date and time to whatever they want. Store it using the Firestore server's timestamp:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myChatCollection').doc().set({
  'timeStamp': ServerValue.timestamp
});
```

Take note that the time is stored in UTC+0

Change it to this:

```
 addMessage() {
    if (messageEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatMessageMap = {
        "sendBy": Constants.myName,
        "message": messageEditingController.text,
        'time': ServerValue.timestamp,
      };

     FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myChatCollection').doc().set(chatMessageMap);
      DatabaseService().addMessage(widget.chatRoomId, chatMessageMap);

      setState(() {
        messageEditingController.text = "";
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I edited my answer for Firestore. You only have to set the value to ServerValue.timestamp for it to use the server's timestamp @Serhebunse

Comment: What I have to Import for ServerValue?

Comment: You could use the auto import to do it. IIRC, you only have to import firestore for it. The code above will insert a document to myChatCollection. You can place that inside onPressed of a button

Comment: I already have imported firestore but ServerValue is still underline red

Comment: @Serhebunse Sorry, I made a mistake there. You would also have to import this: ```import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';```

Comment: what I have to put in Text(..) in the class MessageTile?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your Text? I thought this is about saving the time to firestore?

Comment: @Serhebunse you would have to do it like documentSnapshot.data()[index]["p"]

Comment: documentSnapshot and index not found